# How to change set of color by another CorelDraw

Tags: color, color-conversion, corel-draw

I need to change set of colors by another one in CorelDraw. For example: I have red shapes and I need to change all red color by same green colors.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can not change red to green with the same colors, but I guess you want to keep the shades of it.

There are several options depending on if the elements are raster or vector.

Probably the easiest way and one that work on both types of graphics is to use Effects>Adjust>Hue/SaturationLightness

[image]

And slide the hue

[image]

You probably want to play a bit with the lightness, because there are many shades of green.

---

If it is vector you probably want to prepare a palette, ungroup your mesh and assign colors you want.

[image]

---

If it is raster you could >Edit the Bitmap

[image]

Once is opened with Photo-Paint, split the channels

[image]

Recombine them inverting green and red

[image]

And save.